# function store array in array then return

Tags: javascript

```
var json = [];
var id = "displayImage1";
var object = "style";

storearray(id, object);

function storearray(_id, _object){
json.push(_id);
_id.push(_object);
return
}
```

i am making a function to store array inside a array then return it, here is my code , it didt work can anyone point out what i did wrong ? or show me how to make function then store array inside array.

so the array will be like this  `json -> id -> object`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/8abub6tm/)

Comment: How about `return json`?

Comment: Because string it is not an array

Comment: You want you josn array to be like `[{id, object}]`?

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) given the arrays, use of variables named `json` and `object` etc.  Can you explain what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to switch the order of the `push` statements? So `_object` is pushed to `_id` which is then pushed to `json`

Comment: Please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/8abub6tm/1/)! Let me know if this what you need?

Comment: can array store array ?? instant using object

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're not looking for an array, but for an object, with the id as keys and the object as a value.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var json = {};
json[id] = object
```

This would result in `json` containing `{'displayImage1': 'style'}`

Comment: can array store array ?? instant using object

Comment: Yes, an array can store an array, or objects, and vice-versa. Not sure I understand what you mean by "instant using object"

Comment: oh what need is json is a array and i need to store the id as name and object as a array. thank

Comment: Show us what the final JSON should look like.